# how to loop through the folders but not any other files in a folder

Tags: python, directory

I can work around it by explicitly mentioning the file names in a list and skip the loop if the file is found in the list. But is there any explicit function or a way to do this?

My folder has a lot of folders and a bunch of individual files (shortcuts,.pptx, .xlsx, .docx,...) the folder directory.

Comment: You only want a specific folder, not recursive? Use [`Pathlib is_dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_dir) after globbing everything in a path.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir). When you're looping over all of the files in the directory, simply write:

```
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isdir(f):
        do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work

```py
import os

path = "/home/you/Documents"
dir = os.listdir(path)

for i in range(len(dir)):
  if not os.path.isdir(path+""+dir[i]):
    print(dir[i])
```